# Как отправить js запрос заполняя данные на сайте

Tags: javascript

Пожалуйста, помогите отправить запрос на сайт, заполняя input (на другом сайте) и нажать на кнопку, тоже input

Любым способом пожалуйста

[image: код сайта]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то необходимо по запросу с одного сайта, заполнить данные на другом сайте. Для такой задачи можно использовать puppeteer (надеюсь правильно написал), если у конкретного сайта нет определённого API.

Comment: Здравствуйте, да правильно, поняли, спасибо за ответ, другие почему-то либо игнорят вопрос, либо ставят минус, типо вопрос тупой... спасибо за ответ